# UserChoid ProgId for Edge returns static Appx value - but can it change over time?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, microsoft-edge

The following function returns "AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v" if Edge is your default browser.  Chrome returns "ChromeHTML" and IE returns "IE.HTTP".

Is there a possibility or likelihood that the Edge browser value will change over time?  If I write some C# local code, and the value changes it would obviously cause a problem.

Thanks...

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
public static class BrowserUtils
{
    static public string GetSystemDefaultBrowser()
    {
        string _retval = string.Empty;
        const string userChoice = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice";
        using (RegistryKey userChoiceKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(userChoice))
        {
            if (userChoiceKey == null)
            {
                _retval = "unknown-> userChoiceKey returned null";
            }

            object progIdValue = userChoiceKey.GetValue("Progid");
            if (progIdValue == null)
            {
                _retval = "unknown->GetValue(Progid) returned null";
            }
            //_retval = String.Format("progId=[{0}]", progIdValue.ToString());
            _retval = progIdValue.ToString();
        }
        return _retval;
    } 
}
```